# How do I get job counters in Hadoop 2.7.1?

Tags: hadoop, ambari, hadoop-2.7.2

Im trying to get all counters from specific job using java...
I've wrote working code for Hadoop 0.23.1:

```
    JobClient client = new JobClient(new JobConf(createConfiguration()));
    RunningJob job;
    system.out.print("Looking for job with title containing the string '" + jobName + "'");
    List<JobStatus> jobStatusList = Arrays.asList(client.getAllJobs());

    Collections.sort(jobStatusList, new Comparator<JobStatus>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(JobStatus o1, JobStatus o2) {
            return (o1.getStartTime() < o2.getStartTime()) ? 1 : (o1.getStartTime() > o2.getStartTime() ? -1 : 0);
        }
    });

    for (JobStatus jobStatus : jobStatusList) {
        job = client.getJob(jobStatus.getJobID());
        if (job.getJobName().contains(jobName)) {
            system.out.print(String.format("Job Name '%s' was found in job ID: %s...", jobName, jobStatus.getJobID().toString()));
            return job.getCounters();
        }
    }
    system.out.print("Did not find job that contains the string '" + jobName + "'. Counters are set to null.");
```

Any idea why it's not working in 2.7.1?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is expected output and what do you get?

Comment: for Hadoop0.23.1 I get all counter in current job. In Hadoop 2.7.1 I get nothing... I guess it's related to the fact that there is no JobTracker in 2.7.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeeded with REST API:

```
http://<history server http address:port>/ws/v1/history/mapreduce/jobs/{jobid}/counters
```